# How should I handle asynchronous calls when initializing my BLoC?

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, bloc, flutter-provider

I'm using the `Provider` package to provide a BLoC object (hand-written, not using `bloc` or `flutter_bloc` packages) to my Flutter app.  I have a few asynchronous calls that need to be made to initialize the BLoC properly (for example, settings and other saved info from `SharedPreferences`).  So far, I've written those `async` calls into a few separate functions that are called inside my BLoC's constructor:

```
class MyBloc {

  MySettings _settings;
  List<MyOtherStuff> _otherStuff;

  MyBloc() {
      _loadSettings();
      _loadOtherStuff();
  }

  Future<void> _loadSettings() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    // loads settings into _settings...
  }

  Future<void> _loadOtherStuff() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    // loads other stuff into _otherStuff...
  }
}
```

I want to guarantee that `_loadSettings()` and `_loadOtherStuff()` complete before we get too far into the app so that the code that depends on settings/other stuff has the right info loaded (for example, I want settings to be loaded before I go out to make some network calls, initialize notifications, etc.).

As far as I understand, constructors can't be asynchronous, so I can't `await` on the constructor.  I've tried giving my BLoC an `init()` function (or something similar) that calls `_loadSettings()` and/or `_loadOtherStuff()`, but I'm having a hard time finding a good place to put it.

Where should I be putting these calls?  Or am I just misunderstanding `async/await`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a stream to listen for completion.

```
class MyBloc {

  MySettings _settings;
  List<MyOtherStuff> _otherStuff;

  final _completer = StreamController<Void>.broadcast();

  Stream<void> get completer => _completer.stream;


  MyBloc() {
    allInit();

  }

  allInit()async{
    await _loadSettings();
    await _loadOtherStuff();
    _completer.sink.add(null);
  }

  Future<void> _loadSettings() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();


    // loads settings into _settings...
    return;
  }

  Future<void> _loadOtherStuff() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    // loads other stuff into _otherStuff...
    return;
  }


}
```

And then you use a streamBuilder

```
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: myBloc.completer,
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('loading...');
    //stuff to run after init
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ended up using some help from Future.wait():

```
Future.wait([_loadSettings(), _loadOtherStuff()]).then((_) => _doMoreStuff());
```

Which makes sure that the first two are done before we move on.